# Azure DHCP Options

Tags: azure, dhcp

It appears that Azure doesn't provide many DHCP options for new VMs. On a new client, I looked at the registry entry HKLM/System/ControlSet001/Services/TCPIP/Parameters/Interfaces and found only these options:

- Default gateway
- DHCPDomain (set to reddog.microsoft.com)
- Name Server
- Domain

I found a thread from 2018 stating that the only DHCP option admins can modify is the DNS server list. All other options can't be set in DHCP.

I can't find any newer information, and I'm wondering if, in 2023, Azure had added the ability to specify DHCP server options.

If not, we're curious about the best way to set options like DNS suffix for the host and the DNS suffix search order.